# Programming obstacle avoidance for arduino robot car (4 wheel drive) will not follow our custom moveset

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm trying to program a routine for my arduino robot car so that it will navigate a simple obstacle course. The objective is to do line tracking up to a 17"x12" box and drive around it. i could not figure out a way for it to smartly move around the box so instead i tried to give it a custom moveset to move around the box( instead of it detecting the box, breaking the line following and doing obstacle avoidance i have it stop at the box, move right for a few seconds, move forward a few seconds, move left a few seconds, forward, and then left to manually go around the box). For some reason the robot will stop at the box, turn left, and just stop. i believe its rotating off of the line its programmed to follow and getting confused because there is no longer any line to follow. any help would be greatly appreciated as to this is my introduction to programming and im very lost. I apologize for so many comments in the code I had to learn what was happening line by line and this is how i reviewed what was actually happening.

[code]

```
// Include the Servo library
#include <Servo.h>
// Define object 'myservo' to control the sensor
Servo myservo;

//The pin CONSTANTS for the line tracking sensors
#define LT_R !digitalRead(10)
#define LT_M !digitalRead(4)
#define LT_L !digitalRead(2)

// The pins CONSTANTS for other stuff
#define ENA 5
#define ENB 6
#define IN1 7
#define IN2 8
#define IN3 9
#define IN4 11

// A constant for our car speed
#define carSpeed 130

// Define variables to store the value of the sensor readings
int Echo = A4;  
int Trig = A5; 
// Define variables to hold our right, left, and middle distance values
int rightDistance = 0, leftDistance = 0, middleDistance = 0;

// Function to go forward
void forward(){
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go forward!");
}
void forward(int delayTime){
  int secDelay = delayTime*1000;
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go forward!");
  delay(secDelay);
}

// Function to go backward
void back(){
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  Serial.println("go back!");
}

// Function to go left
void left(){
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go left!");
}
void left(int turnAngle){
  int turnTime = 4*turnAngle;
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  Serial.println("go left!");
  delay(turnTime);
}

// Function to go right
void right(){
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW); 
  Serial.println("go right!");
} 
void right(int turnAngle){
  int turnTime = 4*turnAngle;
  analogWrite(ENA, carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW); 
  Serial.println("go right!");
  delay(turnTime);
} 


// Function to stop
void stop(){
   digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
   digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
   Serial.println("Stop!");
} 

// Function to measure distance with the ultrasonic sensor
int Distance_test() {
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);   
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);  
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);   
  float Fdistance = pulseIn(Echo, HIGH);  
  Fdistance= Fdistance / 60;       
  return (int)Fdistance;
}  
void avoidObject(){
  // Take a reading of what is in front of us  
  middleDistance = Distance_test();
  // Print the result in the Serial monitor
  Serial.print("Middle Distance = ");
  Serial.println(middleDistance);

  // If the distance to an obstacle is less than 20
  if(middleDistance <= 20) {
    int lastTurnLeft = 0;     
    // STOP!
    stop();
    // Wait half a second
    delay(500);
    // Now go in reverse                         
    //back();
    // And set the servo to point right
    myservo.write(0);
    // Wait a second...
    delay(200);
    // stop.
    stop();
    
    //  Read the distance to any obstacle that may be on the right      
    rightDistance = Distance_test();
    // Print the right distance on the serial monitor
    Serial.print("Right Distance = ");
    Serial.println(rightDistance);
    // Wait half a second
    delay(500);
    // Return the ultrasound sensor to the middle position
    myservo.write(90);
    // Wait another half a second to give the sensor a chance to catch up              
    delay(500);
    // And now set the servo to point to the left                                                  
    myservo.write(180);
    // Wait another half a second so it can catch up.              
    delay(500);
    // Take a reading to any obstacles that may be on the left
    leftDistance = Distance_test();
    // Print the left distance on the Serial monitor
    Serial.print("Left Distance = ");
    Serial.println(leftDistance);
    // Wait half a second
    delay(500);
    // Return the ultrasound sensor to the middle position
    myservo.write(90);
    // And wait a second              
    delay(1000);
    // Now, if the obstacle on the left is close to us
    if(rightDistance > leftDistance) {
      // Then let's go right
      right();
      delay(1000);
      stop();
     
    }
    // Else if the obstacle on the right is closer to us
    else if(rightDistance < leftDistance) {
      // Then let's go left
      left();
      delay(1000);
      stop();
     
    }
    // Break out of the object avoidance code
  }
}
bool isColliding(){
  int dist = Distance_test();
  if(dist <= 20){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

// Function to Initialize the Arduino
void setup(){
  // Attach the servo to pin 3
  myservo.attach(3);
  // Start the Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);     
  // Define the mode of our pins
  pinMode(Echo, INPUT);    
  pinMode(Trig, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LT_R,INPUT);
  pinMode(LT_M,INPUT);
  pinMode(LT_L,INPUT);
  // Stop the car
  stop();
  // Put the sensor in the middle position 
  myservo.write(90);
}



    //At this point we should have found a line
    // Simply let the function return and
    // let loop() function handle the line tracking agai`enter code here`n
    enter code here

void loop() {
  int colCount = 0;
  // This is where the loop begins
  bool collision = isColliding();
  // LINE FOLLOWER
  while((LT_M||LT_R||LT_L)&&(collision==false)){
  // If we detect the middle sensor
    if(LT_M){
      // Then go forward
      forward();
    }
    // Else if we detect the RIGHT sensor
    else if(LT_R) {
      // Then go right
      right();
      // And keep going right until we don't detect anything on the right sensor
      while(LT_R);                             
    }
    // Else if we detect something on the left sensor
    else if(LT_L) {
      // Then go left
      left();
      // And keep going left until we don't detect anything on the left sensor
      while(LT_L);  
    }
    avoidObject();
  }  
  if (collision == true){
   colCount==1;
    while (colCount==1){
    right(90);
    forward(5);
    left(90);
    forward(10);
    left(90); 
    forward(5);
    right(90);  
    colCount=colCount+1;
    }
    
    
  }
  else{  
    
   
   stop();
  }
  
  
  // OBJECT AVOIDANCE
  // 17" x 12" box

  
// Go back to the start of the loop                     
}

// What happens: line tracks fine, stops at box fine, once it turns it will not go, professor suggests its detecting the wall so turn right instead?
```

[/code]